# How do I simulate inputs and outputs in a C++ code from a Python script using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11, ctypes

Is there a simple way to use a python script as a proxy for testing a C++ program? I'm currently trying to do it with ctypes, but no clue of how to make it work.

As a proxy I mean a script capable of providing the program inputs and evaluating its outputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "inputs" and "outputs"? If it's just stdin and stdout, or command-line arguments and stdout, or files read and written, you don't have any use for `ctypes` at all, just `subprocess` (if even that). If it's clicking stuff in a GUI, you may or may not be able to do that with `ctypes`, but it's probably easier to automate it in via Windows messages or Cocoa methods. And so on. So, you need to explain what you mean.